# Signature Generation using PKCS#7 Specifications

Tags: java, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I want to prepare a digital signature over some content using PKCS#7 specifications(only Signed Data). I am getting signer certificates by accessing SMART card device. I am using BouncyCastle as a provider in Java and using getEncoded method of CMSSignedData class but the output i am getting is not right and its not working. Can anybody tell me the correct procedure or some sample code to doing the same

Answer (score 1):

prepare a signedData using

```
crypto.signText("textTosign","ask")
```

'byteArr' will be ur signedData it  will BASE64 encoded do decode it pass that to CMSSignedData

```
CMSSignedData csd = new CMSSignedData(byteArr);
CertStore cStore = csd.getCertificatesAndCRLs("Collection", "BC");
        SignerInformationStore signers = csd.getSignerInfos();
        Collection<SignerInformation> lstSigner = signers.getSigners();
```